# Getting ConflictException: An error occurred (ConflictException) when calling the DetectAnomalies operation:

Tags: aws-lambda

While integrating **Lambda** function with **Amazon Lookout for Vision** cannot able to detect the image whether it is defective or not. Getting this error while using lookoutvision.detect_anomalies method while running the code.

> ConflictException: An error occurred (ConflictException) when calling
> the DetectAnomalies operation: Detect cannot be performed when the
> resource is in TRAINED. The resource must be in HOSTED to perform this
> action

````
import boto3

lookoutvision = boto3.client('lookoutvision')
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #print(json.dumps(event))
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']    
    response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    print(response)
    content_type = response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPHeaders']['content-type']
    image = response['Body']
    image_body = image.read()
    
    #res = lookoutvision.list_projects()
    #print(res)
    
    project_name = "new"
    model_version = "3"

    lookout_response = lookoutvision.detect_anomalies(
        ProjectName=project_name,
        ModelVersion=model_version,
        Body=image_body,
        ContentType=content_type
    )
    print(lookout_response)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before using the `lookoutvision.detect_anomalies` api need to start the model using
`start_model()` api.

Also use `stop_model()` to stop the model after anomaly is detected beacuse running the model when is not used will increase the cost.

Refer https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-lookout-for-vision/blob/main/Amazon%20Lookout%20for%20Vision%20Lab.ipynb for code sample